# How do I confirm automation perform status -- running or not?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, php, automationstudio

I want to confirm automation perform status.

How do I confirm this by PHP via SOAP-API?

PHP sample code is here.

```
require('../ET_Client.php');

const OBJ_TYPE        = "Automation";
const ACTION_TYPE     = "start";
const AUTOMATION_NAME = "[Automation name]";

try {
    $authStub = new ET_Client();

    // Get ObjectID
    $props = array(
        'ProgramID',
        'Name'
    );
    $filter = array(
        'Property' => 'Name',
        'SimpleOperator' => 'equals',
        'Value' => AUTOMATION_NAME
    );
    $automationInfo = new ET_Get($authStub, OBJ_TYPE, $props, $filter);
    var_dump($automationInfo);
    $objectID = $automationInfo->results[0]->ObjectID;

    // Perform automation immediately
    $props = array(
        'ObjectID' => $objectID
    );
    $response = new ET_Perform($authStub, OBJ_TYPE, ACTION_TYPE, $props);
    var_dump($response);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of your code -- working or not.  It will benefit those coming after you.

Answer (score 1):

You do a `RetrieveRequest` on the `Automation` object and filter on the `CustomerKey` of your Automation.

The `Status` is returned in the result.  It'll be one of these values:

```
-1   Error
 0   BuildingError
 1   Building
 2   Ready
 3   Running
 4   Paused
 5   Stopped
 6   Scheduled
 7   Awaiting Trigger
 8   InactiveTrigger
```

Here's a [**SSJS example**](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/a268a989daf0867bc028).  Structure would be the same if you're using the SDK.